# NestJs: Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs

I am using `graphql-request` as a GraphQL client to query a headless CMS to fetch stuff, modify and return to the original request/query. headless cms is hosted separately fyi.

I have the following code :

```
@Query(returns => BlogPost)
  async test() {
    const endpoint = 'https://contentxx.com/api/content/project-dev/graphql'
    const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {
      headers: {
        authorization: 'Bearer xxxxxxx',
      },
    })
    const query = gql`
      {
        findContentContent(id: "9f5dde89-7f9b-4b9c-8669-1f0425b2b55d") {
          id
          flatData {
            body
            slug
            subtitle
            title
          }
        }
      }`

    return await graphQLClient.request(query);
  }
```

`BlogPost` is a model having the types :

```
import { Field, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { BaseModel } from './base.model';
import FlatDateType from '../resolvers/blogPost/types/flatDatatype.type';

@ObjectType()
export class BlogPost extends BaseModel {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  id!: string;

  @Field((type) => FlatDateType)
  flatData: FlatDateType;
}
```

and `FlatDateType` has the following code

```
export default class FlatDateType {
  body: string;
  slug: string;
  subtitle: string;
  title: string;
}
```

it throws the following exception :

> Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL output type for the "flatData". Make
> sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.

What is missing in here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How is your graphql server supposed to understand the type of `FlatDataType` when there's no information about it being passed to the graphql parser? You need to add the graphql decorators to it as well. `@ObjectType()`, `@Field()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`FlatDataType` is not defined as `@ObjectType()`, therefore type-graphql (or @nestjs/graphql) can't take it as an output in GraphQL.